# AngularJs - Array.push() inside $http.get() produces a flawed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, http-get

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. It seems to be a javascript issue.

I'm loading a local txt file using **$http.get** (*is there a different way?*). I want to push this content into an array. For the sake of testing, I'm just pushing any string just to be sure that it doesn't have to do with the actual txt file.

```
 var myArray = [];
 $http.get(localFilePath).then(
        function(success){
            myArray.push("123");
        },
        function(error){
            // other stuff
        });

console.log(myArray);
```

This **simple code** will not generate a proper array. Here's a screenshot from Chrome dev tool if I *console.log* the array created:

[image]

Now, this looks like a proper array but it's not. If I `console.log(myArray.length)` it **returns 0**.

Here's instead how a proper array should look like using the same code `myArray.push("123")` **outside** `$http.get()` function:

[image]

Can someone tell what is the difference between the 2 arrays and why the first one is created differently if I do it inside **$http.get()** function?

Comment: Can you show where you're console logging the array? Is it inside the success function or outside?

Comment: @Soviut I'm console logging outside the success function

Comment: you should edit your question and include that since it's critical to the answers we've given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous issue. You're calling `console.log()` outside the promise's "resolve" function.

```
var myArray = []
$http.get(localFilePath).then(function(result) {
  myArray.push("123")
})

// outside resolve function     
console.log(myArray)
```

Since this is an asynchronous operation, that resolve function is only called once the `$http.get()` request finishes (usually a few hundred milliseconds later). However, it does NOT wait, so the rest of the code continues to run. So it kicks off the `get()`, then immediately runs the `console.log()` before the http request has had a chance to finish so it hasn't populated the array by the time `console.log()` is called.

If you were to put the `console.log()` inside the resolve function, you'd see the array was correctly populated because it waited for the http request to finish, populated the array, and only *then* did it print the result.

```
$http.get(localFilePath).then(function(result) {
  myArray.push("123")

  // inside resolve function     
  console.log(myArray)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are console.logging before the array gets the value most likely, and  inside the console, chrome updates the array (since it's a reference) but not the length (since it's a primitive).  Which is why as part of the array you can see the length property set properly.
If you do:

```js
var myArray = [];
let $http = { get: () => {
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('hi'), 1000);
    })
    return p;
}}
 $http.get('').then(
  function(success){
      myArray.push("123");
      console.log(myArray, myArray.length, 'after');
  },
  function(error){
      // other stuff
  }
);
console.log(myArray, myArray.length, 'before');
```

You can see what I mean.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the first part of your code. How can I edit my code so that when I console log outside of the function the array is ready?

Comment: You wait until it's ready - use `.then` or pass in a callback

Answer (score 0):

I have understand your problem and tried below code and I am getting same array this is correct.  your are assigning pushing an object returning from service instead of array.Array.push() will work same with in $http.get() service and out side $http.get() service

```
  var myArray = [];
  $http.get(localFilePath).then(
    function(success){
        myArray.push("123");
       return success
    },
    function(error){
        // other stuff
     return success
    });

  console.log(myArray);
  var myArray2 = [];
  myArray2.push("123");
  console.log(myArray2);
```